# Is there any existing grok{} pattern for date format YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I was checking the nginx error logs at our server and found that they start with date formatted as:

```
2015/08/30 05:55:20
```

i.e. `YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss`. I was trying to find an existing grok date pattern which might help me in parsing this quickly but sadly could not find any such date format. Eventually, I had to write the pattern as:

```
%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM}/%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?
```

I am still hoping if there is a shorter pattern for the same ?

Comment: Does the pattern _actually_ have to contain `[T ]` and `%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?`? Looking at your single example they're unnecessary. Also, why make the seconds optional?

Comment: Agree with you. These are not necessary. But is there any pattern available that can parse this date format as it is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. You find the [included patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) on github. The comment to `datestamp` seems to fit to your YYYY/MM/DD, but `DATE_US` and `DATE_EU` are different.

I suggest overload the `DATE` pattern using grok option [patterns_dir](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-patterns_dir) and go with `DATESTAMP`.

```
DATE_YMD %{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM}/%{MONTHDAY}
DATE %{DATE_US}|%{DATE_EU}|%{DATE_YMD}
```

or just add your pattern into a patterns-file and use grok's patterns_dir option.

Comment: But how would that matched pattern be parsed into a proper date type? I think the other answer should be merged here.

Answer (score 6):

Successful timestamp capture strategy comprised of 3 things

1. Precision and timezone in the original log. Change your nginx timestamp log format.

Use `$msec` to capture milliseconds. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to sort it precisely.

```
log_format custom '[$msec] [$remote_addr] [$remote_user] '
                  '"$request" $status '
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

2. Raw timestamp. Use greedy matching to capture raw data into a field.

Use GREEDYDATA:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "\[%{GREEDYDATA:raw_timestamp}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
  overwrite => [ "message" ]
}
```

3. Parsed timestamp. Use `date` filter to parse raw timestamp.

[reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
date {
  match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.S z" ]
  target => "@timestamp"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To match 2015/08/30 05:55:20, use:

```
%{DATESTAMP:mytimestamp}
```

Tested on Logstash 6.5

Source:
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply include the joda.time pattern which is simple and short.

```
date {
  match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  target => "@timestamp"
}
```

Helpful link for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html